# Unable to send delete request using python

Tags: python

I am trying to delete a record by triggering a DELETE API using python

I login, enter the MFA code using python and then submit the delete request. I have extracted the JWT_TOKEN after login and placing it in the delete request. Following is my code for the Login, MFA verification and Delete request

Login

```
import requests,hmac,base64,struct,hashlib,time,mysql.connector
import win32com.client
import paramiko
import pyotp
import time
api_url="https://cpm-api-qa.aprivada.com/api/v1/users/login"
todo = {"email":"pchaubal+21022023SP@cytrio.com","password":"Cytrio@123"}
response = requests.post(api_url, json=todo)
token = response.json().get('jwt_token').get('token')
time.sleep(45)
```

MFA Code

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this     
case,
                                # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
print (body_content)
sub1="Console."
sub2="This"

idx1 = body_content.index(sub1)
idx2 = body_content.index(sub2)

res = ''
# getting elements in between
for idx in range(idx1 + len(sub1) + 1, idx2):
    res = res + body_content[idx]

# printing result
print("The extracted string : " + res.strip())

mfa_verify_url = "https://cpm-api-qa.aprivada.com/api/v1/users/mfa/verify"

todo = {"code":res.strip(), "email":"pchaubal+21022023SP@cytrio.com", "jwt_token":token}
print(todo)

headr = ""
print (headr)
response = requests.post(mfa_verify_url, json=todo, headers={'Authorization': 'Token     
'+token})
```

Delete request

```
for x in range (1):
    x=2663
    session=requests.session()
    session.trust_env = True
    tenant_delete_url = "https://cpm-api-qa.aprivada.com/api/v1/tenants/"+str(x)
    #headers = "{'Authorization': '" + token + "'}"
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Token {token}'}
    #print('Authorization '+headers)
    #response = requests.delete(tenant_delete_url, headers={'Authorization ': 
    f'{token}'})
    response = requests.delete(tenant_delete_url, headers=headers)
```

Even after suppling the header in th delete request, I get User not logged in.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: We dont know what's wrong, becasue you did not tell us what the problem is. What is the error ?

Comment: I get a 'user not logged in' error when I run the code. I should get back a response code corresponding to delete

Comment: Am I missing some critical parameter here?

Comment: I don't know what the API expects, so it is hard to know what is wrong. However, shouldn't f'Token {token}' be f'Bearer {token}' ?

Comment: Even after changing to f'Bearer {token}', I get 'User not logged in'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by establishing a session and using the session to execute the API calls. Working code is given below

```
import requests,hmac,base64,struct,hashlib,time,mysql.connector
import win32com.client
import time
api_url="https://cpm-api-qa.aprivada.com/api/v1/users/login"
todo = {"email":"pchaubal+21022023SP@cytrio.com","password":"Cytrio@123"}
session = requests.session()
response = session.post(api_url, json=todo)
token = response.json().get('jwt_token').get('token')
time.sleep(45)
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
print (body_content)
sub1="Console."
sub2="This"

idx1 = body_content.index(sub1)
idx2 = body_content.index(sub2)

res = ''
# getting elements in between
for idx in range(idx1 + len(sub1) + 1, idx2):
    res = res + body_content[idx]

# printing result
mfa_verify_url = "https://cpm-api-qa.aprivada.com/api/v1/users/mfa/verify"
todo = {"code":res.strip(), "email":"pchaubal+21022023SP@cytrio.com", "jwt_token":token}
session.headers={'Authorization': 'Token '+token}
response = session.post(mfa_verify_url, json=todo)
print(response.json())
for x in range (1):
    x=13
    tenant_delete_url = "https://cpm-api-qa.aprivada.com/api/v1/tenants/"+str(x)
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Token {token}'}
    response = session.delete(tenant_delete_url, headers=headers)
    print(response.json())
```